# JS How to run code posted by user in a TextArea?

Tags: javascript, forms, canvas, textarea

I was wondering how to run JS code posted by a user in the TextArea when he presses button without refreshing the entire page. I want to have a canvas, a TextArea and a button. When the button is pressed, it runs code from the TextArea and then paints stuff on the canvas.

I know how to put the posted code into variable string.

What I don't know is how to run code in that string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to wrap code in `eval()` function. [It evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Example:

```
eval(new String("2 + 2")); // returns a String object containing "2 + 2"
eval("2 + 2");             // returns 4
```

In your case you will need to read code from text area and pass it to `eval()` it could look something like this:

```
eval(document.getElementById('textareaid').value);
```

Comment: Thanks for this lightning fast and valuable answer. Exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: It's kind of unsafe to use eval for something like that, possibly dangerous, although "lightning fast".

Comment: @RaphaelSpoerri Hi, could you give me an example of vulnerability by using JS eval, please.

Comment: @RaphaelSpoerri So how would one do an XSS attack using JS eval?

Comment: [Stack overflow: why is eval bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Comment: @RaphaelSpoerri Doesn't say anything about XSS.

Comment: @RaphaelSpoerri Yeah, the top answer is out of date, also the question is `loaded`. So if one cannot do XSS otherwise it would be in the answers of `eval bad` question, what other vulnerabilities does `eval` expose you to?

Comment: The simplest problem can result when not being careful with interfaces that involve eval. I don't know so much about XSS though, the XSS problem is just what I heard.

Answer (score 0):

If it is HTML just send it to a variable with a submit button and than
document.write("variable").

Comment: He said **without** refreshing the entire page, what document.write inevitably does.

Answer (score 0):

The safest and simplest way to do it that I know is with node.js:

```js
function runStr (i){
    var vm = require ('vm');
    var box = {};
    vm.createContext(box);
    vm.runInContext(`prgm = function(){return ${i};}`, box);
    return box.prgm();
}
console.log(runStr("2 + 2")); // 4
```